# go back to impersonator user after logout impersonated user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

To implement an authenticate as other users mechanism in laravel, I'm using [404labfr/laravel-impersonate](https://github.com/404labfr/laravel-impersonate) package.

Impersonate as other users works fines. But after a impersonated user logs out parent user (impersonator user) logs out too , while I'm looking for a solution that after impersonated user logouts go back to impersonator user session.

It even seems there is not any built-in method for that.

Anyway, Now I don't know how can I solve this problem. if anyone knows please help me.

Comment: Why not just create new session for the impersonator user? Sorry I never use mentioned library.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know this script is work or not, but you can try this one.

First, you must create the middleware and copy this script.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class PreventBackHistory
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        return $response->header('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate')
                        ->header('Pragma','no-cache')
                        ->header('Expires','Sun, 02 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
    }
}
```

Second you can add into kernel and add into routemiddleware like this example

```
'prevent-back-history' => \App\Http\Middleware\PreventBackHistory::class,
```

And the last, you can add into your middleware route to call that.

I hope this one is works and help your problems.

Answer (score 0):

I found that can do my desired result like this :

```
public function doLogout ()
        {
            if (Auth::check()) {
                if (Auth::user()->isImpersonated()) {

                    $manager        = app('impersonate');
                    $impersonatorID = $manager->getImpersonatorId();

                    $manager->leave();

                    Auth::loginUsingId($impersonatorID);
                    return ['success' => true];
                }

                Auth::logout();

                return ['success' => true];
            } else {
                return ['success' => false];
            }
            /*return Redirect::to('admin/login');*/
        }
```

In the logout operations, first must check that current user is Impersonated or not if yes should used  `$manager->leave();` to logout him.